# Can I reload QEMU/KVM config without restarting VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have production Ubuntu server with a lot of clients. Restarting client's VM is impossible.

However I want to change KVM configuration, because I want to open TCP port in /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf.

Is it possible?